# Was Rabbi Yossei a member of Beth Shammai?

Tags: rabbis, mishna, tannaim, beis-shammai

Was Rabbi Yossei a member of [Beth Shammai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Shammai)?

I am talking about the Rabbi Yossei of [Berakhot Perek 2 Mishna 3](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.2.3?lang=he-en&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all). He is opposed in this Mishna to Rabbi Yehuda, a member of Beth Hillel.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jose_ben_Halafta), especially [WP in Hebrew](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99), might be a good place to start researching.

Comment: I am not comfortable with hebrew unfortunately.

Comment: That's all right; it's there to help other people find an answer to your question....though I search "שמאי" and "הלל" on that page, and didn't find any hits....which doesn't mean much, because WP is not exhaustive.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36635 as well as http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51015 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50910 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50966

Answer (score 4):

According to Tosafos Yeshanim at the end of Maseches Yoma, stam Rabi Yosei is Rabi Yosei ben Chalafta. So I'll point out these ideas from here
http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8789-jose-ben-halafta
Which point to him being non-affiliated with either school.

> It is very likely that he studied much under his father, Ḥalafta, whose authority he invokes in several instances (B. Ḳ. 70a; Me'i. 17b). But his principal teacher was Akiba, whose system he followed in his interpretation of the Law (Pes. 18a; Yeb. 62b).
>
> ...
>
> He was opposed to controversy, declaring that the antagonism between the schools of Shammai and Hillel made it seem as if there were two Torahs (Sanh. 88b). For the most part, Jose adopted a compromise between two contending halakists (comp. Ter. x. 3; 'Er. viii. 5 [= 86a]; Yoma iv. 3 [= 43b]).